# Android how can I take the access token from the authServerCode?

Tags: android, google-api, access-token, google-signin

So this is my googleApiClient:

```
 gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestServerAuthCode(serverID)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(PSSignInFlowActivity.this)
            .enableAutoManage(this/* FragmentActivity */, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

This is what happens when I press the login button:

```
public void login(){
    Log.i("", "handleSignInResult login:");
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

which takes me here:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i("", "handleSignInResult onActivityResult:" + requestCode + ".." + resultCode);
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        Log.i("","handleSignInResult onActivityResult: " +result.getSignInAccount() + ",,," + result.getStatus());
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
```

Which calls this:

```
 private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.i("", "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        String authCode = acct.getServerAuthCode();
//            if(authCode != null)
//                storyFragment.setFromGoogle(authCode);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
    }
}
```

My Issue is that I need an accessToken from the GoogleSignInResult, but I only get back the serverAuthCode. I saw you can exchange the serverAuthCode for an accesstoken on the auth2 playground. Can this be done programmatically?

Comment: Send the auth code to your server and exchange it for an access token as described in the docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
  try{
                    String scope =  "oauth2:" + Scopes.PROFILE;
                    Account account = new Account(acct.getEmail(), "com.google");
                    final String token  = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(PSSignInFlowActivity.this, account, scope);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            storyFragment.setFromGoogle(token);
                        }
                    });
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("","error trying to get client secret : " + e.getMessage());
                }
```

Comment: Without special precautions, doing this will introduce opportunity for access token substitution attack. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/05/improving-security-and-user-experience.html

Comment: Do you have a backend server? If so, send the auth code to your server and exchange it for an access token as described in the docs: developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access